# Get AngularJS constacts

Tags: angularjs

I want to get the constant "ClientID" value from

```
   <script>    
    angular.module("myModule", []).constant("appSetting",

    {
        appEnvironment: 'INTRANET',

        ClientID: '0663555953',

        Scope: 'Level1',
    }    
   );
   </script>
```

located in startPage.aspx

to another js file. i've tried this

```
<script>
var ClientID = angular.module("myModule", []).constant("appSetting").(ClientID);
function myFucntion()
{    
   console.log(ClientID);
}

<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can inject the constant into a controller:

```
    angular.module('myModule').controller('someController',['$scope','appSetting', 
         function($scope, appSetting){
             console.log(appSetting.ClientID);
         }
    ]);
```